# View results from naclports build bots

Tags: google-nativeclient

I would like to be able to easily check if it is only me who is experiencing problems building certain packages on certain architectures, or if it the issue applies to everybody. Being able to see the current build bots stats would be very helpful in this. Is this information publicly available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The naclports waterfall is publicly accessible at (albeit running very slowly...):
http://build.chromium.org/p/client.nacl.ports/

You have to use Ubuntu Precise x86_64, which runs on the bots.